# How do I get the physical address of the page table?

Tags: table

I was trying to get the physical address of the **page table** itself, but kept failing.

The last option I'm going to try, is to modify the kernel code and simply print out the physical address whenever the hierarchical page table is created or extended.

However, is there a different way to check the physical address of the page table? Similar to the way of simply reading /proc/PID/pagemap for finding the virtual to physical mapping.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple misconceptions.

1. On modern processors, especially aarch64, x86_64, there's not one page table; it's a Multilevel structure, and can be distributed pretty arbitrarily in memory space. There's not one address under which you could find it! You need to be specific which architecture, and which level, you mean.
2. It's not necessarily so that every architecture actually has a version of the page table in the physical address space. Especially embedded processor types do have built in memories for just that, and it's simply not in RAM. Again, need to be specific about the architecture you mean.
3. You ask about as if all operating systems are the same - but the way Linux builds page tables and interacts with the mmu isn't necessarily the same that other unixoid operating systems do. You need to be specific which you mean!

> The last option I'm going to try, is to modify the kernel code and simply print out the physical address whenever the hierarchical page table is created or extended.

Interesting that this is your *last* option! User space, i.e., processes that have segmented, protected access to their own virtual memory space, should generally never see Danny physical addresses. In fact, that's a pretty fixed rule for any operating system driver framework I've heard about. If anything exposes physical memory addresses to processes in virtual memory spaces, that thing is broken and must be fixed. Not a bad rule - it avoids dangerous bugs where one allows user space to give manipulated physical addresses back to the kernel and thus access memory the process should have no access to.

I'd strongly recommend you do something else than printing when the page table is extended; that's a bad idea, because whatever that means, it probably ends up in a buffer that then has to grow, this allocating more memory, thus potentially leading to an endless loop. You can use probes on various BSD kernels and Linux to hook such positions.

---

That all being said, in classical 32 bit x86, when in ring 0, the `cr3` register holds the address of the currently active page directory, which holds the addresses of the page tables. Note that this register should be inaccessible to the process being subject to these page tables.

Now, which view at the memory actually applies depends on cr4, namely, whether the process context identifier is set.

So, to get access to the page table addresses, you need to be operating in "kernel mode" if you will, but need to have loaded the page directory base address of your process of interest into CR3. You could probably also directly get the data out of the kernel memory directly by means of a debugger - in the end, switching to a different task requires the base address to be saved in some (os-specific) structure for when the current task needs to be continued.

---

NB that with virtualization, "physical addresses" might actually be just one level up in a nested page table structure. The kernel of a paravirtualized operating system does also never see "real" physical addresses, but I'm not even sure how meaningful the word "real" here is, considering iommu/smmu concepts.

Comment: Thank you so much for the great answer! I actually need to check every location (physical address) of page table, but I might as well start with CR3 to get the top level of the hierarchical page table. As for the virtualized situation, I need the host physical address, not the guest physical address, but I think such situation can wait for now. Thank you again! 
(For my lack of experience on different architectures or OS, I automatically presumed x86_64 and Linux, which I should have clarified in the question.)